# React functional component - when using the fetched data, got error data is underfined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The code is like:

```
const A = (props) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(dataActions.fetchData(personId));
  }, []);
  
  const data = useSelector(state => state.dataReducer.directory);
  console.log("fetch data:" , data);

  ....
  const renderUI = (data) => {
     //process data
     console.log("Data:", data);
     const formattedData = formatData(data);
     return (
       <Directory ....>
     )
  }

  return(
    <div>
     {renderUI(data)} // if comment this line out
    </div>
  ) 
}
```

Both console log show error that data is undefined.
But if comment the `{renderUI}` out, console.log can return the actual data from the redux.

Why this happen and how to fix it? Thanks in advance.

If use:

```
{data && renderUI(data)}
```

It won't alert the error, but the UI is not updated even after the data is fetched successfully. I also tried put data into the useEffect() dependency, still cannot shows any data in UI. Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

1. `console.log("fetch data:" , data)`: Don't write code in component's body, you don't know how many times will be excuted and when will be executed. If you want to see the current value of `data` use `useEffect` hook like:

   ```
   useEffect(() => {
      console.log("fetch data:" , data);
   },[data]);
   ```
2. `console.log("Data:", data);`: Here `data` are undefined just because you didn't pass `data` to function `renderUI`. Modify your code in this way:

   ```
   ...
   return(
     <div>
       {renderUI(data)}
     </div>
   )
   ```

Comment: Thank you. pass the data to renderUI(data) in my code, still got data undefined error. But after comment out that line, can console log the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

I thinks the solution is render data with conditional like

```
{data && <p>renderIU(data)</p>}
```

When component is mounted the result of your fetch is not finish and data will be create before finish them.

Comment: Thank you, it won't alert error if use conditional check. But after the data is fetched, the component is not-rendered. I tried to add the data into the useEffect's dependency, it doesn't work. Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Data that isn't handled in the component state doesn't have to be added to useeffect dependencies, React does it for you. Could you show me the code of the component you paint once you format data?

Answer (score 0):

```
**Hope this help you!**

import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
    
    const CompExample = (props) => {
      const { data } = props;
      return (
        <div>
          <p>Example code</p>
          <p>{data}</p>
        </div>
      );
    };
    
    const App = () => {
      const [data, setData] = useState(null);
    
      const formatedData = () => "test";
    
      useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          setData(formatedData());
        }, 2000);
      }, []);
    
      return <div className="App">{data && <CompExample data={data} />}</div>;
    };
    
    export default App;
```